# How to prevent Bitmap from reloading when Listview is scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

I'm working on an app with a custom ListView that is populated by Bitmaps. The bitmaps are loaded  fine but the only issue is that everytime the ListView is scrolled, the images which come into the view are reloaded, even if they had already been loaded earlier. This wastes time and is rather inefficient. I'd like a way to get the image once, and when the ListView scrolls the bitmaps in and out of the view, they don't have to be reloaded. Here's my code (Just throwing all of it in...you're looking for MainAdapter and AsyncCaller):

```
public class Post extends SherlockActivity implements
    PullToRefreshAttacher.OnRefreshListener, OnItemClickListener {

private PullToRefreshAttacher mPullToRefreshAttacher;
private ListView listview;
private DisplayMetrics metrics;
String[] index = { "023", "143", "564", "982", "023", "143", "564", "982",
        "023", "143", "564", "982" };
String[] summary = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve" };
String[] images = {
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c",
        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTpgdQYIzGWZiDsCtWIMzuZVaZABIwC-3Ym9gvGMcV5OVUdAb-c" };
ActionMode mMode;
Animation animation;
Intent i;
URL img_url;
Bitmap bmp = null;
Holder holder;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null) {
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartBase.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        retrieveData();
        setUpFacebook();
        sessionCheck();
    }
}

private void setUpFacebook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
    FacebookRef.fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    FacebookRef.asyncrunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(FacebookRef.fb);
}

private void retrieveData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Parse work: Get the data and create the list. The data has to have
    // the Bitmaps

}

private void sessionCheck() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // Get the user's data
        listview = new ListView(this);
        listview.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
        int pos = 0;
        // As long as it is less than the number of items in the string
        // array
        for (int i = 0; i < summary.length; i++) {
            strings.add(summary[pos]);
            urls.add(images[pos]);
            pos++;
        }

        MainAdapter mAdapter = new MainAdapter(this, strings, urls, metrics);

        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        setContentView(listview);
        pullToRefresh();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please log in first",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartBase.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

private void pullToRefresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PullToRefreshAttacher.Options ptrOptions = new PullToRefreshAttacher.Options();
    ptrOptions.refreshScrollDistance = 0.6f;
    ptrOptions.headerLayout = R.layout.customised_header;
    ptrOptions.headerTransformer = new CustomisedHeaderTransformer();
    mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this, ptrOptions);
    PullToRefreshAttacher.ViewDelegate handler = new AbsListViewDelegate();
    mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(listview, handler, this);
}

@Override
public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Works",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new AsyncCaller().execute();

        }
    }).start();
    // Notify PullToRefreshAttacher that the refresh has finished
    mPullToRefreshAttacher.setRefreshComplete();
}

static class CustomisedHeaderTransformer extends
        PullToRefreshAttacher.HeaderTransformer {

    private View mHeaderView;
    private TextView mMainTextView;
    private TextView mProgressTextView;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(Activity activity, View headerView) {
        mHeaderView = headerView;
        mMainTextView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.ptr_text);
        mProgressTextView = (TextView) headerView
                .findViewById(R.id.ptr_text_secondary);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReset() {
        mMainTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mMainTextView.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_pull_label);

        mProgressTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressTextView.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPulled(float percentagePulled) {
        mProgressTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressTextView
                .setText(Math.round(100f * percentagePulled) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshStarted() {
        mMainTextView.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_refreshing_label);
        mProgressTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReleaseToRefresh() {
        mMainTextView.setText(R.string.pull_to_refresh_release_label);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefreshMinimized() {
        // In this header transformer, we will ignore this call
    }

    @Override
    public boolean showHeaderView() {
        final boolean changeVis = mHeaderView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE;
        if (changeVis) {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return changeVis;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hideHeaderView() {
        final boolean changeVis = mHeaderView.getVisibility() != View.GONE;
        if (changeVis) {
            mHeaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return changeVis;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu subMenu1 = menu
            .addSubMenu("Categories");
    subMenu1.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Entertainment");
    subMenu1.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Fashion");
    subMenu1.add(0, 3, Menu.NONE, "Business");
    subMenu1.add(0, 4, Menu.NONE, "Books");
    subMenu1.add(0, 5, Menu.NONE, "Kids");
    subMenu1.add(0, 6, Menu.NONE, "Home");

    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 2:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 3:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 4:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 5:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case 6:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.action_account:
        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.action_logout:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Logout?");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_power_off);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Session.getActiveSession()
                                .closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                StartBase.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class Holder {
    public TextView textview;
    public ImageView imageView;
}

public class MainAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> strings;
    private ArrayList<String> urls;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics_;

    public MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> strings,
            ArrayList<String> urls, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        super(context, 0, strings);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.strings = strings;
        this.urls = urls;
        this.metrics_ = metrics;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        final String str = this.strings.get(position);
        final String url = this.urls.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.textview.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.pic);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            img_url = new URL(url);
            holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo);
            new AsyncCaller().execute();
            holder.textview.setText(str);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.anim.push_left_in);

        animation.setDuration(200);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        animation = null;

        return convertView;
    }

}

private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(Post.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdLoading.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());
            bmp = RoundBitmap.roundCorner(bmp, 20);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List item selected",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdDetails.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("index", index[arg2]);
    b.putString("summary", summary[arg2]);
    b.putString("url", images[arg2]);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Leave?");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave?");
        alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_power_off);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process
                                .myPid());
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

  }
```

Comment: try lazy loading image load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good [Training guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) on this in the Android Developer documentation.

Comment: I was too lazy to finish reading it but that's definitely what I need. But from now on the easier option is Picasso :-)

Answer (score 1):

easy method — use picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, excited about the library now, will definitely use it :-) But I think caching is the categorical answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong about this, but what I believe is the issue is that when you scroll the app believes it is undergoing some sort of configuration change. From my most recent experience of writing a threaded process, when rotating the screen I didn't want the download to have to restart or some of the objects to be reloaded. Files that were hardcoded in there remained using their ID's, but the others got redownloaded.

The solution was to use a two methods, one that recognizes when there is a configuration change and then takes the objects wanted and passes them into a weak reference, and then another that asks if we have just come from a configuration change and if so loads those objects from their weak reference.

Comment: Or like the other said, cache them as stated in the developer guide- that's what the ID's do as noted above.

Comment: And you're right, since the adapter populates the ListView one item a a time, it has to keep re-downloading the bitmaps all over since they aren't cached. sigh

Comment: Glad you figured it out!